# Rename the [style] tag to [beer-style]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently [style](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style)'s description and usage is exclusively to talk about beer styles, but wine has different styles as well when referring to taste profiles and production methods.

I think that the current tag should be changed to be [beer-style](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beer-style), or that its description be opened up to not be purely about beer.

Comment: can you give us an example of what you think the description of the tag should be ? As I agree to opening up the description to refer to all alcohol not just beer

Answer (score 3):

**[style](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style) is a redundant tag and should be removed.**

We already have style specific tags such as [stout](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stout), [schwarzbier](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schwarzbier), [imperial-ipa](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imperial-ipa) and [style](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style) is really just a meta/redundant tag in my opinion.